# Monaco Editor :Change default Glyph Margin hover TOOLTIP styling

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, ngx-monaco-editor

I am working on monaco editor and am looking for a way to style the tooltip hover on a glyph margin.

[image]

To achieve the above image I inspected the element and found the css class (hover-row) which I modified as below to get the above styling.

```
.hover-row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
    background : black;
    // margin-left : 10px;
    color : hotpink;
    font-weight : bold;
    font-family : monospace;
    padding : 10px;
    border-radius : 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

I want to know if there is a better way to do this other than relying on the internal css classes of the monaco editor. ? I suspect this could break on any given day.